# smallest subcover to cover sphere using half spheres

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Let $\mathbb{S}^n$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and $\{C_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ be a covering of $\mathbb{S}^n$ consists of closed half spheres, i.e. $C_{\alpha}=\{v\in\mathbb{S}^n|v\cdot x_\alpha\geq 0\}$ for some $x_\alpha\in\mathbb{S}^n$. Moreover, suppose $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ is a closed set. Let $\{C_i\}_{i=1}^{k}$ be a subcover which has least elements among all subcovers of $\{C_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$. It can be proved that $k$ is finite, but can we get an upper bound for $k$ relying only on $n$?

I guess it would be $n+2$. This is true for $n=0,1$. But I'm not sure whether it is true for higher dimensions. I think it is equivalent to the following statement: given $n+3$ points in $\mathbb{S}^n$, if any $n+2$ of them lies in an open half sphere, then all of them lies in an open half sphere. Is this true?

Comment: You cannot even take a finite subcover, e.g. when $n=1$, $v_k = (\cos k^{-1}, \sin k^{-1})$ and $v_0 = (-1, 0)$. Then there is no finite subset of $\{ C_0, C_1, \cdots, \}$ that cover $\mathbb S^1$.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that the $x_\alpha$'s form a closed set.

Comment: May be add that into the post?

Comment: [Helly's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem) seems to be related.

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, updated that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That works if I apply the theorem to the open half balls to get my last statement. Thanks!

Comment: If you've figured out an answer from the comments then you should post it as an answer.